# Count using data from two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a progress column and an email date column. I'd like to have count 3 results as variables:

```
First: Progress = 0
Second: Progress = 1, EmailDate == 0000-00-00 00:00:00
Third: Progress = 1, EmailDate !== 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Currently I have the following:

```
SELECT Progress, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Progress
```

However, it isn't using the Email Date, when I try and use it, I get a zero value.

Comment: This is this related to PHP? This is just a MySQL problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(progress = 0,1,0)) AS Counter_1,
    SUM(IF(progress = 1 AND EmailDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00',1,0)) AS Counter_2,
    SUM(IF(progress = 1 AND EmailDate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00',1,0)) AS Counter_3
FROM myTable
```